# How To read cookie which created from client side javascript in serverside asp.net code

Tags: javascript, asp.net

For Example I have put one cookie on page load with some specific value  on button submit at server side c# code how do i get the value of that cookie ?(asp.net)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Reading Cookie:

```
if (Request.Cookies["NameofCookie"] != null)
{
    string value = string.Empty;
    if (Request.Cookies["NameofCookie"]["yourkey"] != null)
    { value= Request.Cookies["NameofCookie"]["yourkey"]; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to read a cookie in C#:

```
string cookieValue = string.Empty;

if (Request.Cookies["cookiename"] != null)
{
    cookieValue = Request.Cookies["cookiename"].Value.ToString();
}
```